# Network Manger connection icon

Tags: unity, network-manager, panel

I have a problem with connection icon. Even if I not connected to any network icon is showing as connected, this two opposite arrows.
[image]

Comment: That is an annoying bug that has been around for a while. You can make it show the correct thing by running `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` to restart Network Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in virbr0 interface which is always connected and ethernet type. To ignore this interface I added the following lines to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

After restart Network Manager service icon is displayed properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly old bug that is more annoying than harmful, and there is a bug report for this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/1575655. The workaround is to restart Network Manager by running:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

If you want to bring this bug to the developers' attention, please visit the bug report that I linked and click on "Yes, it affects me".

Comment: I marked this bug report as "affect me".

Comment: This trick doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this behavior of NetworkManager (applet) might be that some kind of virtualization software is installed (e.g. qemu/kvm or VirtualBox). If this is the case NetworkManager handles the virtual interfaces as wired networks instead of ignoring them.

As a workaround you could force NM to ignore these interfaces by adding this to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:virbr*,interface-name:vboxnet*
```